# A phrase starting with "In a..." and ending in "...minute" that means 'without hesitation.'

Tags: expressions

I am missing the single word in a common phrase that starts with "In a..." and ends with "...minute" that means 'without hesitation.'

Comment: To me it seems any kind of minute is very different from *without hesitation* - unless you could justify using *in a minute* with no qualification.

Presumably the idea is *a short minute* or *a fraction of a minute* but then how would *in a second* not be better?

Answer (score 4):

A phrase containing a single word in that blank is **in a hot minute**, but there is some confusion over whether that phrase means "in a short time" or its opposite. There is considerable discussion at the ELU question [Since when has “a hot minute” meant a long time?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/390539/49890).

A more common phrase containing a compound proper noun in that blank is **in a New York minute**. [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/New%20York%20minute) defines "New York minute" as a noun meaning **instant** or **flash**.

Comment: I believe the phrase is "in a New York minute."  Thank you.